# What's the most painless way to fix a lot of small holes on the wooden floor

Tags: repair, flooring, floor, hole, hole-repair

For some really stupid reason, I accidentally punched a lot of small holes on my wooden floor. See attached photo. That's a roughly 3 feet by 3 feet area with a lot of small, but shallow holes.

My floor is solid oak or pine wood. Not sure exactly which kind.

What's the most painless way of fixing it other than replacing the wooden floor tiles?

[image]

Comment: What type of floor is this? Solid hard wood floor, engineered floor, faux-wood vinyl tiles, etc. The fix will depend on the exact type you have,

Comment: Do you know if this is real wood or a laminate? If it is real wood and thick enough, sanding should work, but you may have to restain a large area for it to look normal.

Comment: @Jeffrey edited, it's oak or pine solid wood

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it's oak or pine solid wood edited in the op

Comment: I also wouldn't characterize these as *holes* - that would be a much more serious problem. More like "dents".

Comment: You can apply some sort of "filler".  There are several options available.

Comment: once cleaned, you might be able to just fill those with poly as you re-finish. use a squeegee after the 1st coat to smoosh it down into the divots. If filled edge to edge, they should essentially disappear as long as the top coat is smooth and even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like dents, if you're not loving the distressed look, try to steam them out.

Comment: Yep - damp towel and a hot clothes iron can work wonders. The floor appears to be oak, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

General recommendation, provided that the wood is thick enough to handle sanding and staining:

Sand the affected area, including some lighter sanding around it to avoid a sudden dip/edge.

If the color is, relatively speaking, only skin deep, you will need to stain the sanded area to match the rest of the room. The catch is that it can be quite hard to not end up with that looking really bad. In which case, a light sanding of the rest of the room, so that you have bare wood everywhere, and then stain the entire floor.

Or just put down an area rug, if that is appropriate given the location and usage.

Answer (score 0):

One trick that can work with dents in wiod is to use a cotton bud to apply moisture to it and give it time to absorb and expand.

Dry, then sanding and finish.